# What is the most appropriate Coldfusion cfsqltype to use for MS SQL's uniqueidentifier field type?

Tags: sql, coldfusion, cfqueryparam

When connecting from Coldfusion 8 to a MS SQL 2008 datasource, what Coldfusion cfsqltype should I use for a SQL column set to 'uniqueidentifier'.

```
<cfquery name="user" datasource="#ds#">
    SELECT id, username
    FROM users
    WHERE id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="WHAT_CF_SQL_TYPE_HERE?" value="#arguments.id#">
</cfquery>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CF_SQL_CHAR or CF_SQL_IDSTAMP

see: http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/Tags_p-q_18.html

Comment: CF_SQL_CHAR is also listed for uniqueidentifier without comment. Does anyone know if there is a difference and/or preference?