# For a ColdFusion cfqueryparam which CFSQLType do you use for TEXT?

Tags: text, types, coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cfqueryparam

So if I have a cfqueryparam, and the datatype in SQL is TEXT, which of the CFSQLTypes do I use? Or do I follow the below link about uniqueidentifiers? Or is it just better to change the datatype to varchar/longvarchar?

- [cfqueryparam documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_p-q_18.html)
- [What is the most appropriate Coldfusion cfsqltype to use for MS SQL's uniqueidentifier field type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949884/what-is-the-most-appropriate-coldfusion-cfsqltype-to-use-for-ms-sqls-uniqueiden)

Answer (score 7):

I have used longvarchar in both cfqueryparam and procparams with good success

```
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_longvarchar" value="#myLongText#">
```

Answer (score 4):

[`text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) is a deprecated data type used for storing *very large* strings (up to 2,147,483,647 bytes). As it says in the documentation, the correct cfsqltype for `text` columns is `cf_sql_longvarchar`.

[`uniqueidentifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx) is a completely different data type. It is used to store small uuid values (36 characters only). So that type does not apply here.